# Multi-Level Exponential Equation

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I solved the equation below by getting similar bases:

$\implies (9^{2})^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 3$  .

$\implies {(3^2)^2}^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 3$

$\implies (3^{2 \times 2})^{\frac{4x-1}{5}}  = 3^1$

$\implies 4 ^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 1$

$\implies (2^{2})^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 1$

$\implies 2^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 2^{-1}$

$\implies {\frac{4x-1}{5}} = -1$.

I solved the equation $x = -1$.

My question is what rule does not allow you to solve this equation by simply saying  $ (9^2)^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 3 $.

Then, $\ln 81^{\frac{4x-1}{5}}= \ln 3$
$\implies {\frac{4x-1}{5}}\times \ln 81 = \ln 3$ and proceed from here.

Intuitively it seems too easy, but I'm looking for the rule(s) that would make it clear this is not a correct way. Sorry for an ignorant question: I'm an engineer--not an applied mathematician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infact, your second method is the correct one. In your first method.you made a mistake :
$\implies (3^{2 \times 2})^{\frac{4x-1}{5}}  = 3^1$
$\implies 4 ^{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 1$ ,whereas it should have been $4 .{\frac{4x-1}{5}} = 1$ (as laws of exponents : $(a^m)^n = (a^n)^m = a^{mn}$) which reults in $x=\frac{9}{16}$ and the result agrees with your second method.

Answer (score 0):

From the line
$$\Bigg(3^4\Bigg)^{\dfrac{4x-1}{5}}=3^1$$
it *does not follow* that
$$4^{\dfrac{4x-1}{5}} = 1.$$

Rather, what actually follows is
$$3^{\dfrac{4(4x-1)}{5}}=\Bigg(3^4\Bigg)^{\dfrac{4x-1}{5}}=3^1$$
where we have used the following rule of exponents:
$$(a^m)^n = (a^n)^m = a^{mn}$$
where $a$ is a real number.

Since the exponential function $f(X) = 3^X$ is one-to-one, it follows that
$$\dfrac{4(4x-1)}{5} = 1$$
which means that
$$4x - 1 = \dfrac{5}{4}$$
$$4x = \dfrac{9}{4}$$
$$x = \dfrac{9}{16}.$$

Comment: Thank you, Arnie.

Comment: @Frederick If you feel that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please click the green check mark next to the answer. Thanks!